# Is it possible to ALWAYS keep the cursor active in the text editor while using Browser Refresh with Sublime Text 3?

Tags: google-chrome, sublimetext3, browser-refresh

I'm using Browser Refresh with Sublime Text 3 on Windows. Every time I save, Google Chrome refreshes. This behavior is correct. However, when it does this, it activates the Chrome window even though I have "activate" set to false. This makes it so that I always have to click back into Sublime Text to make more edits, slowing down my workflow.

Here's what's in my sublime-keymap (Key Bindings - User):

```
[
{
  "keys": ["ctrl+s"], "command": "browser_refresh", "args": {
    "auto_save": true,
    "delay": 0.5, 
    "activate": false,
    "browsers" : ["chrome"]
  }
}
]
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know which Operating System you're using. On Windows the `activate` option is always `true`.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you. I'm definitely on Windows, so is there any way to fix that?

Comment: I don't know, but it's my guess that this setting doesn't support Windows for a reason. Maybe have a look at a third-party tool that keeps the focus on specific windows, [here are some suggestions](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-prevent-programs-from-stealing-focus-in-windows-2624453).